# How can I delete an array C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have a structure:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned char data[HEX_FLASH_BUFFER];
  bool isLoad;
  unsigned int length;
} s_hexFLASH;

typedef struct {
  s_hexFLASH flash;
} s_hexFile;

s_hexFile *hex = new s_hexFile;
```

How can I delete this whole structure?
Because when a did something like this:

```
delete[] hex->flash.data;
```

After this I'am still able to read data:

```
cout << hex->flash.data[0] << endl;
```

Comment: Not a strict duplicate, but same topic, and the [very famous] answer is the answer to your question too.

Comment: `delete` does not magically turn off bits in your memory, it just marks it as available. In other words, you can still read it, but someone may reuse it for other things at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to delete `data`, because it's not allocated dynamically in the first place. `delete` pairs with `new`. So call `delete hex;`

All that said, in modern C++ you basically don't use the `delete` keyword manually. You use the smart pointers `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` to manage dynamically allocated memory. But it is more usual just to use local (automatic) variables.

Also note: `typedef struct { ... } name;` should be just `struct name {...};`. The former is archaic.

Comment: Or just use a local variable.

Answer (score 4):

`unsigned char data[HEX_FLASH_BUFFER];` defines an array of fixed length with automatic storage duration, which means that it will be deallocated automatically when the structure object is deallocated.

In other words: you haven't allocated it by calling `new[]` so there is no reason to call `delete[]` on it.

Answer (score 1):

`delete` (and `delete[]`) simply deallocate dynamically allocated memory (and run the destructor for non-POD types, but that is not important now).

`data` here has automatic storage duration. Not only does `delete[]` not work here, it causes undefined behavior. A good compiler will warn you if you try do `delete` non-dynamically allocated memory.

Even when memory is no longer marked as 'in-use' you can still access it, but this causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete hex;
```

will delete the memory allocated to the hex structure

Comment: @Lodhart: Well, more importantly to your question, the data array was not allocated dynamically, so there's no need to call delete on it. But hex was allocated dynamically. So that's where you call the delete.

Answer (score 0):

The member data does *NOT* have automatic storage duration.   It has whatever storage duration the class it is the non-static member of has.